# To read another users mailboxsettings with MSGraph does the application really need application level permissions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to read a person's Out of Office text with MSGraph. I understand the only way to do this is by getting the person's [mailbox settings as indicated here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Is there another way to read a person's Out of Office Message?

Assuming there is no other way I then [have read for example in this link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/538) that to call `GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings` you need to have **Application Permissions** for MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite.  Is this still the case? It does not make sense to me that you need Application level permissions. Is there not a delegated (admin consent required) MailboxSettings.Read.All???  The problem is that most IT departments will be hesitant (or pigs are going to fly before some IT departments) give an application this permission to run without a signed in user.

Alternatively, I see that there is a User property of mailboxsettings, thus using the $select query parameter you can call this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}?$select=mailboxSettings` does or should this work with the User.Read.All.

**UPDATE** in accordance with the suggestion below I have added 2 suggestions to the MSGraph user voice.

1. [A person's out of office information should be included with their calendar / freebusy (getschedule) information.](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40679635-a-person-s-out-of-office-status-message-should-be)
2. [There should be a Mailboxsettings.Read.All permission.](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40679446-there-should-be-a-mailboxsettings-read-all-which-i)

Please click on the link and vote them up if you agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no `MailboxSettings.Read.All` or `MailboxSettings.Read.Shared`. You can see the list at https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions. I encourage you to request this as a feature at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com.

One possible approach given the currently available permissions around this API is to use app permissions and configure an [app access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) to limit the mailboxes it can access - if that's the concern you're mentioning. I'm not clear on why it would be preferable to give a user account access to this info for all mailboxes in an org but not an app service principal.

It isn't included as part of `User.Read.All` by design. It's not really a property on the user, it's config stored in the mailbox. It's abstracted as a property in Graph, but it requires additional permissions to access.

Comment: Pity, but thank you for letting me know.  My question has been updated with your suggestion and I have made some suggestions so let us see how it goes.

Comment: Jason 1 thing; is MailboxSettings.Read at application level enough to simply read the information of another user or is ReadWrite also required? I don't want to change anything just read the automaticRepliesSetting properties.

Comment: Yes you can get with only .Read. There was an issue with the service in combination with the way the SDK retrieves the settings that caused it not to work with only .Read. However, this has been fixed in the service so the SDK should be unblocked.